# transforming a normal class member to a static class member

Tags: c++, static

I'm building a "system" so I can later on write in an "action-based" environment. What I want is to give my instance (ie a "car") a certain state (ie parking, driving, starting). Then during some event it ought to perform code depending on the state.

I DON'T want to use a switch/if-then-else statement as that is very errorprone & hard to extend. (To allow for more states). Instead I want to use function-pointers.

The code I have (ignore the sillyness of the functions, they are to demonstrate):

```
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember)) 
enum State {Set, Add, Mul};
class car {
public:
    typedef void (car::*MemFn)(int v);
    car(int v, State _s) : val(v), s(_s) {
        posFunctions.insert(std::make_pair(State(Set),&car::SetVal));
        posFunctions.insert(std::make_pair(State(Add),&car::AddVal));
    }
    void DoIt(int v) {
        //MemFn t = &car::SetVal;
        MemFn t = posFunctions.find(s)->second;
        CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this,t)(v);
    }
    int val;
    State s;
protected:
    std::map<State,car::MemFn> posFunctions;
    void SetVal(int v) {
        val = v;
    }
    void AddVal(int v) {
        val += v;
    }
    void MulVal(int v) {
        val *= v;
    }
};
```

this works as I expect. (I can call create an car object, give it a certain state and then call "doit - which would be the function triggered by the event" to perform the actions).

However there is 1 very annoying thing: I have to create the function-map (which maps the states with the functions to perform) for each car object independently. This isn't really as "in reality" (in reality each car always performs the same when state & event are the same) and thus error prone / ugly.

I tried making "posFunctions" a static map, and using a static initialize function for the 2 lines in the constructor.

> main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class std::map,class std::allocator > > car::posFunctions" (?posFunctions@car@@1V?$map@W4State@@P8car@@AEXH@ZU?$less@W4State@@@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBW4State@@P8car@@AEXH@Z@std@@@4@@std@@A)
>   I guess this is because I access a non static member function - even though it is pointed?

Is it possibly to make the map static (or global)?

Thank you for the help,
paul23

Comment: Your link error aside (which others have answered below already), have you considered using the State Pattern to model this? Might make for a cleaner implementation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, I really need to be more careful with those things.

Comment: Use std::function, or boost::function if your compiler doesn't have it.

Comment: @sgreeve - what do you think he's doing?  Just because it doesn't look like the GoF diagram doesn't mean it's not an implementation of the state pattern.

Comment: @Noah Roberts The logic executed for a given state is encoded in the car object, and the function pointer for calling that logic selected based on the state variable. For me, this is a slightly more complex way of encoding the state pattern than using a sequence of ifs. I'm merely suggesting looking at the variations of the pattern which use polymorphism, embedding the logic for each state in a State object. Seems like a reasonable suggestion to me.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you declare your `map` static, you need to add the following line in your implementation file :

`std::map<State,car::MemFn> car::posFunctions;`

Here's a link to the relevant [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12) item.

Comment: this has just solved an annoying compile error for me, +1 thanks

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to define the map on a global scope, i.e.

`std::map<State,car::MemFn> car::posFunctions;`

in the .cpp file where you define the car.

Generally though, when you make a construct like that, ask yourself - could you do that using polymorphism instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible - you have to **define** the static variable in 1 place (the CPP file for this class most likely).

```
std::map<State,car::MemFn> car::posFunctions;
```

What you have in the header file is just a *declaration*.

This is analogous to the way you have to provide a function *definition* in the .CPP file for each function you *declare* in the header.  If you miss any of the function bodies out, the linker will give you the same error on each missing function.

To initialize this structure on demand, provide a static member function that gets called from your class constructor but checks (in a thread-safe way if needed) whether it's been called before.

```
void car::initFunctions()
{
  static bool done(false);
  if (done)
    return;

  // first pass, set up the map
  done = true;
}
```